# Chameleon question changed from one duplicate to another

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I spotted a question that had an obvious duplicate and closed it with my close-vote hammer.

After following the advice in the duplicate, the OP then edited the question to address a totally different problem. If the new problem were a previously-undiscussed issue, I would have happily retracted my close vote and possibly answered the new question. However, as it happens, the new issue is *also* a duplicate.

What is the recommended course of action here? Currently, I've commented with a link to the new duplicate and kept the question closed under the old duplicate. The ideal scenario is that I re-open the question and someone else correctly closes it shortly afterward; however, this might not happen if the question sees no more attention, and furthermore may not scale for repeated chameleon edits.

Comment: Say hello to the meta effect. I can close it as dupe of the new link, if you re-open it.

Other than that, I'd say you did what you could.

Comment: Teamwork! *\*High five**

Comment: this depends on whether edits like this are legitimate. If they are then you reopen (because incorrect dupe is more confusing for readers than missed one) and prey that others pick it from where you left it. If it isn't, then you rollback the edit and add comment telling the asker to post a new question instead (and warn them that this would also be a dupe:)

Comment: @Cerbrus: you don't have to wait for apsillers to reopen; you have one reopen and one close vote; you could have used them both. :-) If your dupe hammer works for closing, it works for reopening.

Comment: Oh, so the block on close vites if you've already voted doesn't block after a re-open vote :-) good to know.

Comment: Roll back the edit and tell the OP to post a new question. I'd also point out that his new question has an answer and give him a link to the second duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But unfortunately, a single user can't close, reopen, and close again; you can only do two of the three. (Didn't I just find that out the hard way and need your help on a question a couple weeks ago?)

Comment: @abarnet That's right; in this case, Cerberus mistakenly thought he could help me only by doing *one* of the three.

Comment: @abarnert and that is by design and fine. But Cerberus needed to only do two things, not three here.

Comment: No, please don't tell the OP to post a new question if you know it's going to be a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidWallace I've edit to use less strong language: "separate questions should be separate posts" instead of "post a new question" (in addition to preserving my original intent that the duplicate should of course not be posted as a new question).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'll summarize the advice given in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274958/chameleon-question-changed-from-one-duplicate-to-another#comment108290_274958) [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274958/chameleon-question-changed-from-one-duplicate-to-another#comment108444_274958) by [@gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) and [@thegrinner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/264775/thegrinner).

This problem can be resolved in two different ways, depending on the nature of the edits:

**"I thought the OP had an X problem, but I can see now it was a Y problem all along."**

If the edits are "legitimate" then it's appropriate to reopen. A case of "legitimate" question-changing might be a case where the OP explained the original problem poorly or left out critical information. In this case, it was always the same problem all along; it simply appeared to be a different problem in the original text of the question. In this case, it would be very confusing to future viewers to have the wrong duplicate, and the question should be reopened and re-closed with the new duplicate. (Possibly you could enlist help from a chat room to close the question, if it's a very obvious duplicate.)

**"I see that OP had an X problem before, and now he's asking about a new Q problem instead."**

If the edit is "not legitimate," the edit is an attempt to change the question to address a distinctly different problem. In this case, the following steps seem best:

1. roll back the edit so that the question matches the duplicate
2. share a link to the new duplicate in a comment
3. let the user know that fundamentally changing a question is not appropriate, and separate questions should be separate posts (but they shouldn't make a new post out of this question, because it's a duplicate!)